# How to change gallery of template in goodlayers

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I change the gallery in wordpress for home page of http://****/

[image]

Comment: check your console the images are not found re-upload them it will work fine

Comment: i just want to change the another gallery which i hv created...this gallery pics doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Check if that directory really exist or not

Comment: basically i dnt want to use those images...i want too use another gallery

Comment: then create another gallery and upload images and see what happens

Comment: i hv another gallery ready...but i dnt know where to change the gallery....look for the dropdown of changing gallery

Comment: dropdown? do you want to include your newly created gallery instead of old one?

Comment: that's theme specific may be via shortcode check your home page edit section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71063/discussion-between-user1853803-and-vidya-lb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific theme go to admin `dashboard -> Grand college -> Footer slide show` from there you can change the settings..